# Debugging DBCP Tomcat connection pool

Tags: java, database, tomcat

i am using tomcat dbcp in my application,
[Here](http://rapidpaste.com/s/7ea9019df9) is the Resource definition in context.xml

in [Connection manager](http://rapidpaste.com/s/bb442c6977) i am getting connection from pool.

This configuration works on localhost but when i try using this on a hosting server , i am unable to get the connections from the pool.

I have double checked all the settings like db name , username ,password .

As i have no control over the tomcat dbcp , how can i know the root of the problem.
is their any way i can debug the issue ?

**EDIT**

i am able to get the connections from database directly(without dbcp) with the same settings i.e (url,uname,password).

Comment: ¿Did you double checked the host name on hosting server? Because they often use different servers for DB and for applications, so the hostname varies...

Comment: yes i checked that too. and one more thing  : i am able to get the connections from database directly(without dbcp) with the same settings (url,uname,password).

Comment: Directly ?= without pool. If DBCP is having problems on creating a connection, it throws SQLExceptions and IOExceptions (also the ones bubbling from the driver itself) that you should be able to catch from your application. Also, DBCP shouldn't be culprit if you tested it with no problem in your environment. Finally, what error do you see? It would help on diagnose.

Comment: No NamingException in ConnectionManager ..  i just get null when i call ConnectionManager.getConnection

Comment: Don't throw SQLException, catch it and print stacktrace. Also catch Exception (even throwable), all this only for the sake of testing...

Comment: You are right...i should have made it to catch Exception so that i can get the cause. i will try catching Exception now....

Comment: Whey you say you can get the connection directly, you mean using the MySQL driver?  If so then make sure you have the mysql driver on your host, if possible move it from your application's WEB-INF/lib to TOMCAT_HOME/lib

Comment: yes i can get the connections using MySql Driver. and i already tried moving driver to TOMCAT_HOME/lib.

Comment: Please post some code, the XML resource definitions, and a stack trace.

Comment: The rapidpaste links are broken